# Finding cube root of a number less than 1 using binary search

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I am doing `MIT6.00.1x course on edX` and the professor tells that **"If x<1, search space is 0 to x but cube root is greater than x and less than 1"**.
There are two cases :

 1. The number x is between 0 and 1

2. The number x is less than 0 (negative)

In both the cases, the cube root of x will lie between `x and 1`. I understood that. But what about the **search space**? Will the initial search space lie between 0 and x? I think it is not that. I think the bold text as cited from the lecture is a flaw! Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: it seems if 1>x>0, the search space would be x-1?

Comment: @Bobby Exactly!!! But the lecturer says that the search space is 0 to x. I think the statement is a flaw, right?

Comment: yeah I think so. Professors make mistakes all the time. Chill bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your instructor's one statement is a flaw.  For 0 < x < 1, the root will lie between x and 1.  This is true for any power in the range (0, 1) (roots > 1).

You can reflect the statement to the negative side, since this is an odd root.  The cube root of -1 <= x <= 0 will be in the range [-1, x].  For x < -1, your range is [x, -1].  It's the mirror-image of the positive cases.  I'm not at all clear why the instructor made that asymmetric partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the problem you're talking about. The only reason she put that is that she deals with the absolute difference:

`while abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epsilon`

However, the code will need another line to deal with negative cubes all together which will be something along the lines of:

`if cube<0: guess = -guess`

I hope this helps.